# Eclipse Spring MVC Project Configuration Files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, web.xml, applicationcontext

I have created a Spring MVC project through eclipse. I believe I used some plugins to generate the project directory. I find here there configuration files.

1. web.xml
2. root-context.xml
3. servlet-context.xml
4. I am kinda of familiar with Spring MVC & its dependency injection. However I have problems understanding the last two configuration files (root-context & servlet-context).
   What kind of configurations do they contain?
5. Also in may online examples I see mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. Why did eclipse not generate this xml file in my project?
6. [IMPORTANT] I wanted to set up strong security and user authentication for my web app. I have been following online tutorials again and they all create a seperate
   xml file named spring-security.xml and add the namespace information to that file. Does it suffice if I just create this file and add the name space information? I mean
   dont' I need to import this file to a main file that is scanned by Spring framework?
7. How do I define and where do I put spring application context.xml file and start wiring the dependencies together? Also if I define everything (all dependencies here) how is this file picked up by the framework?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Configuration Files**

If you check your web.xml you will find both of `root-context.xml` and `servlet-context.xml`   files being referred here. One used by `Dispatcher Servlet` and other by `Context Loader Listenter`. You can name your files to whatever unless they are being refereed in web.xml

**Eclipse Not generating files**

Every editor works its own way. some may generate full fledged project/app with both `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListner` configured or some with only `DispatcherServlet` ( with minimal configutaion). Check `Spring Roo` it starts with basic and gives you the flexibility to generate  a strong app.

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** is not there

Some of the thing in spring projects are convention based, for example if you are not providing any file to your `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml` spring looks for `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file, and if you have provided it won't look for.

**Spring Security**

To Configure Spring Security you need to provide at least some configuration. But the question is where. You need to add this configuration to your `web.xml` only. and Hence no need to import this to any other file.

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-   class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml                          
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Where to define application context.xml**

Just define it any where, configure beans in it.
 You can add this file as follows:

a) Either Import this into some other configuration file like `root-context.xml` or `servlet-context.xml`
    as  `<import resource="application-context.xml"/>`

b) Add  this into web.xml with `ContextLoaderListner` as `context param`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath*:META-INF/spring/application-context*.xml
            classpath*:META-INF/spring/abc*.xml
     </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Great Answer! Answers almost everything I wanted to know. Although I may add that I have all the security configurations inside spring-security.xml file and reference it inside <context-param> in web.xml. Provides for nice organization and code separation of concerns.